# Background color not filling full entire row height when using my-auto

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, background, row, height, fill

I have a boot-strap row where a i want the first column to have blue background and text to be centered vertically and horizontaly.

If I don't center text horizontally it works
HTML

```html
 <div class = "shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" style="padding: 0 !important;">
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row main-row">
                <div class="col-2 booking-flight-info-dir text-center   " style="">
                        <img  src="<?= plugin_dir_url( __DIR__ ).'/img/out_flight_icon.png'?>" alt="out_flight_icon.png" style="padding-left:10px " >
                        <span >תיסת הלוך</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 booking-flight-info-flightnum text-center  my-auto" style="">
                <span>טיסה מספר:</span><BR>
                <span style="font-size: x-large;font-weight: bold;text-align: center"><?= $rowData->outTrip->flightNmr?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

[without my-auto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCXjv.png)

However once I add my-auto to center tex horizontally, the background color is don't fill entire row-height, only the area of the text.

```
<div class = "shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" style="padding: 0 !important;">
<div class="container">

        <div class="row main-row">

            <div class="col-2 booking-flight-info-dir text-center my-auto " style="">
                    <img  src="<?= plugin_dir_url( __DIR__ ).'/img/out_flight_icon.png'?>" alt="out_flight_icon.png" style="padding-left:10px " >
                    <span >תיסת הלוך</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-2 booking-flight-info-flightnum text-center  my-auto" style="">
            <span>טיסה מספר:</span><BR>
            <span style="font-size: x-large;font-weight: bold;text-align: center"><?= $rowData->outTrip->flightNmr?></span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


</div>
```

[with my-auto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STQJ6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it like this

```
<div class="shadow p-3 mb-2 bg-white rounded" style="padding: 0 !important;">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="row main-row  ">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="row flight-num-row h-100 ">
                        <div class="col booking-flight-info-dir text-center d-table" style="">
                        <div class="d-table-cell align-middle">
                            <img src="<?= plugin_dir_url(__DIR__) . '/img/out_flight_icon.png' ?>" alt="out_flight_icon.png"
                                 style="padding-left:10px ">
                            <span>טיסת הלוך</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col booking-flight-info-flightnum text-center   d-table" style="line-height: 1">
                         <div class="d-table-cell align-middle">
                        <span>טיסה מספר:</span><BR>
                        <span style="font-size: x-large;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;"><?= $rowData->outTrip->airline . ' ' . $rowData->outTrip->flightNmr ?></span>
                         </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The contents below is based on Bootstrap 5 (but also working fine on Bootstrap 4).

I don't use `my-auto` but add `justify-content-center align-items-center d-flex` instead. The `text-center` is no need either.

```
<div class = "shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" style="padding: 0 !important;" dir="rtl">
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row main-row">
                <div class="col-2 booking-flight-info-dir justify-content-center align-items-center d-flex" style="">
                        <i class="fas fa-plane"></i>
                        <span >תיסת הלוך</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 booking-flight-info-flightnum text-center  my-auto" style="">
                <span>טיסה מספר:</span><br>
                <span style="font-size: x-large;font-weight: bold;text-align: center">22</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

See it in action [1](https://jsfiddle.net/5j6ua94z/), [2](https://jsfiddle.net/eaLm7cf9/).

Don't just copy and paste because I was modified your HTML to be able to run via jsfiddle.

If you use `my-auto` the browser will be wrap that element to its actual height and then set margin top & bottom to automatically. With that, you can't have full element height and align text into vertically middle.

Comment: Thanks, what I did in then end was to use d-table on class and then div d-table-cell  align-middle